# iptables, haproxy and connstate

Tags: iptables, haproxy

i have two haproxy servers that are in HA mode via corosync, each of them is configure to pass traffic to certain services, i.e. clamav, from particular servers.  Though when i test this i am able to `telnet [lb ip] 3310` from a non-lb ip address and successfully connect.
At the top of my rules i have:

```
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

Relevant configuration on table

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  11.11.11.11       anywhere             tcp dpt:3310
ACCEPT     tcp  --  22.22.22.22       anywhere             tcp dpt:3310
ACCEPT     tcp  --  23.23.23.23       anywhere             tcp dpt:3310
```

I'm wondering if these two rules are getting in the way of each other and they could be better defined.  I am running these services on cloud servers in different datacenters/racks for redundancy, which is why i am trying to secure these ports to be accessible only from known servers.

Thanks, hopefully that is sufficient information.  The default INPUT policy is DROP and all DROPPED packets are logged.  I can see proper rejections in the logs, which is good and all other packets are flowing nicely.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with `state NEW`, when  changed to `state RELATED, ESTABLISHED` all works as intended.

I came to this conclusion after comparing ufw iptable rules and my own iptable rules that i'm trying to automate via salt.

Also tips from this resource [IPTablesHowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo) that i should have read closer.

Hopefully this will help someone else.